# Using Slider Removes UITableView actions like button pressing or scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, slider, tableview

Link to download XCODE project to better understand what is happening: https://ufile.io/qcwxd

NOTE: I used Cocoa pods to install LCSliderMenu so open the right workspace.

Problem:

Start the project and see how the table works, try clicking the buttons.

When you are done Navigate to `ViewController.swift` and then to `ViewDidLoad` then uncomment the function `example()`
Now run the project again and see how the table is non-responsive.

Obviously i am thinking that the slider takes over the whole gesture recogniser for the tableView also the action for the buttons. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the side menus are covering the table , try this

```
 view.addSubview(slideMenu)
 view.insertSubview(slideMenu, belowSubview: self.tableView)
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. Could you care to explain how you saw that it was like that so i can think the way you just did and see things more clearly.

Comment: if u un check line that gives the background to the slide menu you will see them covering the table

Comment: True, i even uncommented that cause i did not want it to change the bg color on the whole screen should have thought of that. Thank you!